# Shrink panel width to that of content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to have a panel shrink the width of a panel to the width of the content.  I am hoping to have the panel wrap an image in the body and then have the caption in the footer but I don't like the panel spanning the full width of the surrounding container div.

The html I am using currently is:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" alt="some alt text" src="a_path_to_a.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer text-venter">A caption describing the image above.</div>
</div>
```

I am open to alternative ideas, I'm new to bootstrap and web development in general.

Answer (score 0):

use the javascript or jquery, if you want to set div width to set to image width.

Here is my sample code to set all div has class panel set to inner img width.
I hope would helpful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var actualImgWidth = 0;
        $(".panel").each(function () {
            actualImgWidth = $("img", this).width();
            $(this).width(actualImgWidth);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've just tried this and it breaks the img-responsive class and requires a refresh to resize the image to fit any change in screen size.  Also it seems to left align where I would like a center alignment.